# Criteria for a sheaf to be locally free over subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $\mathcal{F}\to X$ a sheaf.

Is there a regularity criteria (or a condition) for  $\mathcal{F}$ that determines whether we there exists a closed subvariety $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$ and a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ such that $\mathcal{F}=i_*\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: The natural choice for $Y$ will be the scheme-theoretic support of $\mathcal F$. Do you have something in mind for the $Y = X$ case?